# apache james config error on windows

Tags: james

I'm trying to run  apache james 2.3.2.1 mail server on my windows but when runnig the server it give me an error  on the config file

```
   C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd C:\Users\Wassim\Desktop\james-2.3.2.1\bin

C:\Users\Wassim\Desktop\james-2.3.2.1\bin>run.bat
Using PHOENIX_HOME:   C:\Users\Wassim\Desktop\james-2.3.2.1
Using PHOENIX_TMPDIR: C:\Users\Wassim\Desktop\james-2.3.2.1\temp
Using JAVA_HOME:      C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91

Phoenix 4.2

org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component named "users-store" failed to pass through the Starting stage. (Reason: org.apache.avalon.framework.service.ServiceException: Cannot find or init repository (Key='')).
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleHelper.fail(LifecycleHelper.java:354)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleHelper.startup(LifecycleHelper.java:226)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.startup(DefaultApplication.java:530)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.doRunPhase(DefaultApplication.java:478)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.runPhase(DefaultApplication.java:409)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.start(DefaultApplication.java:180)
        at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.start(ContainerUtil.java:260)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.kernel.DefaultKernel.startup(DefaultKernel.java:295)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.kernel.DefaultKernel.addApplication(DefaultKernel.java:376)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.deployer.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:357)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.deployFile(DefaultEmbeddor.java:542)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.deployFile(DefaultEmbeddor.java:535)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.deployFiles(DefaultEmbeddor.java:520)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.deployDefaultApplications(DefaultEmbeddor.java:509)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.execute(DefaultEmbeddor.java:268)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.frontends.CLIMain.run(CLIMain.java:198)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.frontends.CLIMain.execute(CLIMain.java:184)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.frontends.CLIMain.main(CLIMain.java:145)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.launcher.Main.startup(Main.java:135)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:84)
Caused by: org.apache.avalon.framework.service.ServiceException: Cannot find or init repository (Key='')
        at org.apache.james.core.AvalonMailStore.select(AvalonMailStore.java:309)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.BlockInvocationHandler.invoke(BlockInvocationHandler.java:134)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.select(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.james.userrepository.UsersFileRepository.initialize(UsersFileRepository.java:153)
        at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.initialize(ContainerUtil.java:244)
        at org.apache.james.core.AvalonUsersStore.initialize(AvalonUsersStore.java:131)
        at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.initialize(ContainerUtil.java:244)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleHelper.startup(LifecycleHelper.java:200)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:307)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.apache.james.core.AvalonMailStore.select(AvalonMailStore.java:277)
        ... 33 more
There was an uncaught exception:
```

and print me for stack trace

```
org.apache.avalon.phoenix.interfaces.DeploymentException: Failed to start application james.
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.deployer.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:379)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.deployFile(DefaultEmbeddor.java:542)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.deployFile(DefaultEmbeddor.java:535)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.deployFiles(DefaultEmbeddor.java:520)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.deployDefaultApplications(DefaultEmbeddor.java:509)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.execute(DefaultEmbeddor.java:268)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.frontends.CLIMain.run(CLIMain.java:198)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.frontends.CLIMain.execute(CLIMain.java:184)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.frontends.CLIMain.main(CLIMain.java:145)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.launcher.Main.startup(Main.java:135)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:84)
Caused by: org.apache.avalon.framework.CascadingException: Failed to start application james.
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.kernel.DefaultKernel.startup(DefaultKernel.java:313)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.kernel.DefaultKernel.addApplication(DefaultKernel.java:376)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.deployer.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:357)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.avalon.phoenix.interfaces.ApplicationException: Component named "users-store" failed to pass through the Starting stage. (Reason: org.apache.avalon.framework.service.ServiceException: Cannot find or init repository (Key='')).
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.start(DefaultApplication.java:186)
        at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.start(ContainerUtil.java:260)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.kernel.DefaultKernel.startup(DefaultKernel.java:295)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component named "users-store" failed to pass through the Starting stage. (Reason: org.apache.avalon.framework.service.ServiceException: Cannot find or init repository (Key='')).
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleHelper.fail(LifecycleHelper.java:354)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleHelper.startup(LifecycleHelper.java:226)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.startup(DefaultApplication.java:530)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.doRunPhase(DefaultApplication.java:478)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.runPhase(DefaultApplication.java:409)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.start(DefaultApplication.java:180)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: org.apache.avalon.framework.service.ServiceException: Cannot find or init repository (Key='')
        at org.apache.james.core.AvalonMailStore.select(AvalonMailStore.java:309)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.BlockInvocationHandler.invoke(BlockInvocationHandler.java:134)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.select(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.james.userrepository.UsersFileRepository.initialize(UsersFileRepository.java:153)
        at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.initialize(ContainerUtil.java:244)
        at org.apache.james.core.AvalonUsersStore.initialize(AvalonUsersStore.java:131)
        at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.initialize(ContainerUtil.java:244)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleHelper.startup(LifecycleHelper.java:200)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:307)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.apache.james.core.AvalonMailStore.select(AvalonMailStore.java:277)
        ... 33 more
rethrown from
org.apache.avalon.framework.CascadingException: Failed to start application james.
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.kernel.DefaultKernel.startup(DefaultKernel.java:313)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.kernel.DefaultKernel.addApplication(DefaultKernel.java:376)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.deployer.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:357)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.deployFile(DefaultEmbeddor.java:542)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.deployFile(DefaultEmbeddor.java:535)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.deployFiles(DefaultEmbeddor.java:520)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.deployDefaultApplications(DefaultEmbeddor.java:509)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.execute(DefaultEmbeddor.java:268)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.frontends.CLIMain.run(CLIMain.java:198)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.frontends.CLIMain.execute(CLIMain.java:184)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.frontends.CLIMain.main(CLIMain.java:145)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.launcher.Main.startup(Main.java:135)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:84)
Caused by: org.apache.avalon.phoenix.interfaces.ApplicationException: Component named "users-store" failed to pass through the Starting stage. (Reason: org.apache.avalon.framework.service.ServiceException: Cannot find or init repository (Key='')).
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.start(DefaultApplication.java:186)
        at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.start(ContainerUtil.java:260)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.kernel.DefaultKernel.startup(DefaultKernel.java:295)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component named "users-store" failed to pass through the Starting stage. (Reason: org.apache.avalon.framework.service.ServiceException: Cannot find or init repository (Key='')).
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleHelper.fail(LifecycleHelper.java:354)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleHelper.startup(LifecycleHelper.java:226)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.startup(DefaultApplication.java:530)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.doRunPhase(DefaultApplication.java:478)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.runPhase(DefaultApplication.java:409)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.start(DefaultApplication.java:180)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: org.apache.avalon.framework.service.ServiceException: Cannot find or init repository (Key='')
        at org.apache.james.core.AvalonMailStore.select(AvalonMailStore.java:309)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.BlockInvocationHandler.invoke(BlockInvocationHandler.java:134)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.select(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.james.userrepository.UsersFileRepository.initialize(UsersFileRepository.java:153)
        at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.initialize(ContainerUtil.java:244)
        at org.apache.james.core.AvalonUsersStore.initialize(AvalonUsersStore.java:131)
        at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.initialize(ContainerUtil.java:244)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleHelper.startup(LifecycleHelper.java:200)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:307)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.apache.james.core.AvalonMailStore.select(AvalonMailStore.java:277)
        ... 33 more
rethrown from
org.apache.avalon.phoenix.interfaces.ApplicationException: Component named "users-store" failed to pass through the Starting stage. (Reason: org.apache.avalon.framework.service.ServiceException: Cannot find or init repository (Key='')).
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.start(DefaultApplication.java:186)
        at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.start(ContainerUtil.java:260)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.kernel.DefaultKernel.startup(DefaultKernel.java:295)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.kernel.DefaultKernel.addApplication(DefaultKernel.java:376)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.deployer.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:357)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.deployFile(DefaultEmbeddor.java:542)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.deployFile(DefaultEmbeddor.java:535)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.deployFiles(DefaultEmbeddor.java:520)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.deployDefaultApplications(DefaultEmbeddor.java:509)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.execute(DefaultEmbeddor.java:268)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.frontends.CLIMain.run(CLIMain.java:198)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.frontends.CLIMain.execute(CLIMain.java:184)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.frontends.CLIMain.main(CLIMain.java:145)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.launcher.Main.startup(Main.java:135)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:84)
Caused by: org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component named "users-store" failed to pass through the Starting stage. (Reason: org.apache.avalon.framework.service.ServiceException: Cannot find or init repository (Key='')).
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleHelper.fail(LifecycleHelper.java:354)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleHelper.startup(LifecycleHelper.java:226)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.startup(DefaultApplication.java:530)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.doRunPhase(DefaultApplication.java:478)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.runPhase(DefaultApplication.java:409)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.start(DefaultApplication.java:180)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: org.apache.avalon.framework.service.ServiceException: Cannot find or init repository (Key='')
        at org.apache.james.core.AvalonMailStore.select(AvalonMailStore.java:309)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.BlockInvocationHandler.invoke(BlockInvocationHandler.java:134)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.select(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.james.userrepository.UsersFileRepository.initialize(UsersFileRepository.java:153)
        at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.initialize(ContainerUtil.java:244)
        at org.apache.james.core.AvalonUsersStore.initialize(AvalonUsersStore.java:131)
        at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.initialize(ContainerUtil.java:244)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleHelper.startup(LifecycleHelper.java:200)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:307)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.apache.james.core.AvalonMailStore.select(AvalonMailStore.java:277)
        ... 33 more
rethrown from
org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component named "users-store" failed to pass through the Starting stage. (Reason: org.apache.avalon.framework.service.ServiceException: Cannot find or init repository (Key='')).
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleHelper.fail(LifecycleHelper.java:354)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleHelper.startup(LifecycleHelper.java:226)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.startup(DefaultApplication.java:530)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.doRunPhase(DefaultApplication.java:478)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.runPhase(DefaultApplication.java:409)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.start(DefaultApplication.java:180)
        at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.start(ContainerUtil.java:260)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.kernel.DefaultKernel.startup(DefaultKernel.java:295)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.kernel.DefaultKernel.addApplication(DefaultKernel.java:376)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.deployer.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:357)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.deployFile(DefaultEmbeddor.java:542)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.deployFile(DefaultEmbeddor.java:535)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.deployFiles(DefaultEmbeddor.java:520)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.deployDefaultApplications(DefaultEmbeddor.java:509)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.execute(DefaultEmbeddor.java:268)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.frontends.CLIMain.run(CLIMain.java:198)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.frontends.CLIMain.execute(CLIMain.java:184)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.frontends.CLIMain.main(CLIMain.java:145)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.launcher.Main.startup(Main.java:135)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:84)
Caused by: org.apache.avalon.framework.service.ServiceException: Cannot find or init repository (Key='')
        at org.apache.james.core.AvalonMailStore.select(AvalonMailStore.java:309)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.BlockInvocationHandler.invoke(BlockInvocationHandler.java:134)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.select(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.james.userrepository.UsersFileRepository.initialize(UsersFileRepository.java:153)
        at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.initialize(ContainerUtil.java:244)
        at org.apache.james.core.AvalonUsersStore.initialize(AvalonUsersStore.java:131)
        at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.initialize(ContainerUtil.java:244)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleHelper.startup(LifecycleHelper.java:200)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:307)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.apache.james.core.AvalonMailStore.select(AvalonMailStore.java:277)
        ... 33 more
rethrown from
org.apache.avalon.framework.service.ServiceException: Cannot find or init repository (Key='')
        at org.apache.james.core.AvalonMailStore.select(AvalonMailStore.java:309)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.BlockInvocationHandler.invoke(BlockInvocationHandler.java:134)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.select(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.james.userrepository.UsersFileRepository.initialize(UsersFileRepository.java:153)
        at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.initialize(ContainerUtil.java:244)
        at org.apache.james.core.AvalonUsersStore.initialize(AvalonUsersStore.java:131)
        at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.initialize(ContainerUtil.java:244)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleHelper.startup(LifecycleHelper.java:200)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.startup(DefaultApplication.java:530)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.doRunPhase(DefaultApplication.java:478)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.runPhase(DefaultApplication.java:409)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.start(DefaultApplication.java:180)
        at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.start(ContainerUtil.java:260)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.kernel.DefaultKernel.startup(DefaultKernel.java:295)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.kernel.DefaultKernel.addApplication(DefaultKernel.java:376)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.deployer.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:357)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.deployFile(DefaultEmbeddor.java:542)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.deployFile(DefaultEmbeddor.java:535)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.deployFiles(DefaultEmbeddor.java:520)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.deployDefaultApplications(DefaultEmbeddor.java:509)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.execute(DefaultEmbeddor.java:268)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.frontends.CLIMain.run(CLIMain.java:198)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.frontends.CLIMain.execute(CLIMain.java:184)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.frontends.CLIMain.main(CLIMain.java:145)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.launcher.Main.startup(Main.java:135)
        at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:84)
```

It looks like there is some errors while configuration on the 
I tried to to do some corrections like [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JAMES-1631)
but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there is a problem with this version,there is an update who works fine for me [here](https://people.apache.org/~eric/james-2.3.2.2-SNAPSHOT/james-binary-2.3.2.2-SNAPSHOT.tar.gz)